# How to spawn random objects as waypoints on scene depending no height?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script will work fine if i have a terrain in the scene but i don't have a terrain this case :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public int numberOfObjects;
    public float duration;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;

    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;


    void Awake()
    {
        //Get terrain size
        terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
        terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

        //Get terrain position
        xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
        zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

        StartCoroutine(Generate());
    }

    IEnumerator Generate()
    {
        //Generate the Prefab on the generated position
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfObjects; i++)
        {
            //Generate random x,z,y position on the terrain
            float randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(xTerrainPos, xTerrainPos + terrainWidth);
            float randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(zTerrainPos, zTerrainPos + terrainLength);
            float yVal = Terrain.activeTerrain.SampleHeight(new Vector3(randX, 0, randZ));

            //Apply Offset if needed
            yVal = yVal + yOffset;

            GameObject objInstance = (GameObject)Instantiate(prefab,
                new Vector3(randX, yVal, randZ), Quaternion.identity);

            if (duration > 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(duration);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my scene i have some mountains objects not my own it's from a package.
and i want to spawn random objects around the mountains.

[image: scene]

example of one of the mountains objects :

[image: mountain]

Comment: `Awake() { ... StartCoroutine(...); ... }` - BTW, that's not how you should allow scripts to run during Unity's **Editor** mode.  Though you could use `[ExecuteInEditMode]` a better way is to create a `public class SpawnObjectsEditor : Editor { ... }` and in your `OnInspectorGUI()` add a **Spawn** button to the UI.  That way users can click the **Spawn** button to populate the scene on a needs basis rather than bringing the Editor to a halt with unwanted calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your terrain has a mesh collider, you can `Raycast`. Raycasting is basically simulating a line from one point, going in a direction until it hits a collider. Info in this [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html).

### How to use it

1. We set the first argument to:

   Vector3 origin = (randomX, 999f, randomZ);

   Baically, we get a random number in the x and z. (**Must be within the dimensions of the mountain**) Also, it must be above the mountain, so set the `y` to a number larger than the mountain' height.
2. The second one should be Vector3.down (we are checking where the position hits the mountain)
3. Output the position that it hit.

Code for it:

```
...// in class
float fromX, toX, fromZ, toZ;
RaycastHit hit;
...
//In the coroutine
Vector3 mPos = mesh.bounds.center + transform.position;
fromX = -mesh.bounds.extents.x + mPos.x;
toX = mesh.bounds.extents.x + mPos.x;
fromZ = -mesh.bounds.extents.z + mPos.z;
toZ = mesh.bounds.extents.z + mPos.z;

float randX = Random.Range(fromX, toX);
float randZ = Random.Range(fromZ, toZ);
Vector3 checkPos = new Vector3(randX, 999f, randZ);

if (Physics.Raycast(checkPos, Vector3.down, our hit)
{
   Vector3 OUTPUT = hit.point;
}
else
{
   Debug.Log("No point found");
}
...
```

**Edit:**

If you want to automatically get toX get `mesh.bounds.extents.x + mesh.bounds.center + transform.position`.
**I edited the script**

Comment: there is no terrain in the scene.  each mountain object is not on a terrain. the mountain object have a child and the child have a mesh collider. but there is no terrain in the scene.

Comment: It doesn't matter. It still should work if you put in the right values

Comment: working. how can i draw a ray to the hit point but keep the drawing lines and not to delete and draw over again but to keep all the random lines it's drawing ? i did this but it's drawing a new line each time and not keeping them.  if (Physics.Raycast(checkPos, Vector3.down, out hit))
        {
            Vector3 OUTPUT = hit.point;
            Debug.DrawRay(checkPos, hit.point, Color.red);
        }

Comment: How do i know what are the x from to and z from to ? i entered from 0 to 7425 on the x 7425 is the x position and from 0 to -2765 on the z position is that right ?

Comment: @BenziAvrumi **1.** to make the raycast last longer, add a 4th argument for how long it should last. **2.** I will edit soon, but for now, fromX is where the mesh starts on x axis, and toX is where it ends. Similar to startZ